# Keep Element At The Bottom Of the Parent ELEMENT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple animation. Take a look at it. http://jsfiddle.net/5wJ5D/

MY QUESTION:

How can I make the children elements stay at the bottom of the screen. After the animation goes for a while, all the elements eventually go to the bottom because eventually one of them is height:100%.. how can I get the elements to be at the bottom of the screen even before this happens?

JavaS:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    $('#container').prepend('<div style="height:'+height+'0%"></div>');
}, 500);
html, body, #container {
    height:100%;
}
#container > div {
    width:20px;
    background:black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I tried position:absolute; bottom:0.. but that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: I tried that but I wont work because element out of flow and not inline

Comment: just give the parent element `position:relative` and then do what @Stilly.stack said.

Comment: doesnt work http://jsfiddle.net/8t7st/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution require that you wrap your container with an other div. I've called it `outerContainer`. Once you have that and set its height at 100%, you can use the display `table` trick :

```
#outerContainer{
    display : table;
}

#container{
    display : table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5wJ5D/2/

Comment: No problem, you should also look at j08691 answer. It solve an other problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background property to a linear-gradient and set the inner div heights to 100%

CSS

```
html, body, #container {
    height:100%;
}
#container > div {
    height: 100%;
    width:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

JS

```
var count = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if(count > 10){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    $('#container').prepend('<div style="background: linear-gradient(to top, black '+ height +'0%, transparent '+ height +'0%);"></div>');
    count++;
}, 500);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wJ5D/4/)

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty solution

CSS:

```
#container > div {
    height: 100%;
    width:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

JS:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    $('#container').prepend('<div style="bottom:'+(height-10)+'0%;height:' + height + '0%"></div>');
}, 500);
```